# CodeRay style messed up - how to fix

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-highlighting, redcarpet, coderay

I'm trying to use CodeRay in my project and it seems to be working, however the style and formatting seems to be messed:

[image: Coderay messed up code]

Note that I'm using CodeRay in conjunction with Markdown (Redcarpet). I've added both gems in my gemfile and in the `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` I've added the following:

```
class CodeRayify < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
    def block_code(code, language)
        CodeRay.scan(code, language).div(:line_numbers => :inline)
    end
end

def markdown(text)
    coderayified = CodeRayify.new(:filter_html => true, :hard_wrap => true)

    language ||= :plaintext

    options = {
        :fenced_code_blocks => true,
        :no_intra_emphasis => false,
        :autolink => true,
        :strikethrough => true,
        :lax_html_blocks => true,
        :superscript => true
    }

    markdown_to_html = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(coderayified, options)
    markdown_to_html.render(text).html_safe
end
```

Which does work as you can see by the screenshot attached. The problem is the formatting though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also noticed the current CSS shipped with the CodeRay repo doesn't respond well on mobile/tablet devise.

**To fix, follow the steps below:**

***1. Add this to your CSS:***

/* Displays a scroll bar */

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 7px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

***2. In your app helper file for CodeRay options, ensure the block_code options :line_numbers are set to :inline, like below:***

class CodeRayify < Redcarpet::Render::HTML

```
    def block_code(code, language)
        CodeRay.scan(code, language).div(:line_numbers => :inline)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use table for line_numbers instead of inline?

```
module ApplicationHelper
 class CodeRayify < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  def block_code(code, language)
    CodeRay.scan(code, language).div(:line_numbers => :table)
  end
end

def markdown(text)
  coderayified = CodeRayify.new(:filter_html => true, 
                                :hard_wrap => true)
  options = {
    :fenced_code_blocks => true,
    :no_intra_emphasis => true,
    :autolink => true,
    :strikethrough => true,
    :lax_html_blocks => true,
    :superscript => true
  }
  markdown_to_html = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(coderayified, options)
  markdown_to_html.render(text).html_safe
 end
end
```